# Swift 2.2: Non +1 increasing iterator loops

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, iterator

I was wondering about the best solution regarding the non +1 increasing iterator loops in Swift 2.2 since the old style is now deprecated:

```
for (var i = 0; i < planets.count; i += 1) {
    let string = planets[i]
    if (string == "Venus" || string == "Saturn") {
        i += 2
    }
}
```

My first solution was to use `while` which works

```
var i = 0
while i < planets.count {
    let string = planets[i]
    if (string == "Venus" || string == "Saturn") {
        i += 2
    }
    i += 1
}
```

but is not very handy for using it throughout the your code multiple times. So I created an Array extension which seems to work as well:

```
extension Array {
    func loopIncrement(callback: (inout i: Int) -> ()) {
        var index: Int = 0
        while index < self.count {
            callback(i: &index)
            index += 1
        }
    }
    func loopDecrement(callback: (inout i: Int) -> ()) {
        var index: Int = self.count - 1
        while index >= 0 {
            callback(i: &index)
            index -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

using it like this:

```
planets.loopIncrement { (i) in
    let string = planets[i]
    if (string == "Venus" || string == "Saturn") {
        i += 2
    }
}

planets.loopDecrement { (i) in
    let string = planets[i]
    if (string == "Venus" || string == "Saturn") {
        i -= 2
    }
}
```

For now this is good but I am sure there is a more swifty way to solve this.

So lets start a discussion here. Any help is much appreciated!

Here is the Playground file if you want to have a look: [NonPlusOneIncrementLoops.playground](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d9q4ix1abqfz0kd/NonPlusOneIncrementLoops.playground.zip?dl=0)

**Example:**

In the following example you can see where changing the loop index live is need. 
There is a `printObject` array which contains `PrintObject` classes which define how many times its `printText` should be printed into the debug area. The `printCount` attribute is generated randomly and therefor is not known before the loop.

```
class PrintObject {
    var printCount: Int = 0
    var printText: String = "<Missing>"
}

var printObjects = [PrintObject]()

for i in 0...6 {
    let randomCount = Int(arc4random_uniform(2)) + 1
    let printObject = PrintObject()
    printObject.printCount = randomCount
    printObject.printText = "This is line \(i)"
    printObjects.append(printObject)
}

printObjects.loopIncrement { (i) in
    let printObject = printObjects[i]
    printObject.printCount -= 1
    if printObject.printCount > 0 {
        i -= 1
    }
    print(printObject.printText)
}
```

This obviously is a trivial example but it may make it clearer to some in which cases changing the loops index makes sense.

Comment: Besides incrementing the loop index differently depending on conditions, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's it. The discussion is based only on this.

Comment: Changing iterator inside for-loop is bad code in *any* language. Could you please add the complete use case? How are you using the planets (why are you skipping the next planet?)? There is not one good replacement of `for-loop`, there are many and every one of them is used for different use cases.

Comment: Can you elaborate why exactly it is a bad idea to change the iterator inside the loop?

Comment: Regarding printObjects example - add another nested loop inside (for...i). It looks like much more cleaner approach to me.

Comment: For this example that might be true. But it can get much more complex where another nested loop ist just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a Generator/SequenceType to be able to use the for-in-loop:

```
struct IrregularGenerator<T> : GeneratorType, SequenceType {
    let getIncrement: T -> Int
    var index: Int
    let array: [T]

    init(array: [T], start: Int, getIncrement: T -> Int) {
        guard start >= 0 && start < array.count else {
            preconditionFailure("start index is out of bounds")
        }
        self.array = array
        self.index = start
        self.getIncrement = getIncrement
    }

    mutating func next() -> T? {
        guard index >= 0 && index < array.count else {
            return nil
        }
        defer {
            index += getIncrement(array[index])
        }
        return array[index]
    }
}

let planets = ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"]

for planet in IrregularGenerator(array: planets, start: planets.count - 1, getIncrement: { ($0 == "Venus" || $0 == "Saturn") ? -3 : -1 }) {
    print(planet)
}
```

And here is your PrintObject example rewritten with my IrregularGenerator (which I altered to remove the 0 increment protection, beware, this could provoke an infinite loop):

```
for printObject in IrregularGenerator(
    array: printObjects, start: 0,
    getIncrement: { $0.printCount -= 1; return $0.printCount == 0 ? 1 : 0 }
) {
    print(printObject.printText)
}
```

Comment: If i'm not mistaken here you cannot change the iteration index dynamically depending on conditions. You will have to predefine them before the loop.

Comment: That's as far as you will get with such a solution. for-in-loop values are not modifiable.

Comment: Thats why I created the extension shown in my initial post which use `while` but behave like the old C-Style `for` loop where you could change the index dynamically inside the loop.

Comment: I added sample code in my initial post. Maybe it will be clearer now the task at hand is.

Comment: I updated my answer with your new example (and slightly altered my IrregularGenerator).

Answer (score 0):

If you want only every 2nd element

```
evens = Array(1...10).filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

Much verbose code

```
func isEven(number: Int) -> Bool {
  return number % 2 == 0
}

evens = Array(1...10).filter(isEven)
```

Comment: The problem here is that you cannot change the iteration index dynamically depending on conditions.

Comment: Could you please provide a real life example where you need to change the iteration index dynamically depending on conditions? It doesn't look like there is a trivial workaround for this.

Comment: Just look at my example above. Works fine.

Comment: In your particular planets example I would rather use array.filter method instead of implementing any tricky array loop.

Comment: Filter only works if you know what to filter in advance. In my case I need to skip some planet depending on conditions that change within the loop itself.

Comment: I added sample code in my initial post. Maybe it will be clearer now the task at hand is.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you know the sequence *in advance*, Swift's *Stridable* types (i.e. *Int*) have a `stride(to:by:)` and `stride(through:by:)` methods. Using it like this:

```
for i in 0.stride(to: 10, by: 2) {
  // ...
}
```

The `i` will take the values of `0`, `2`, `4`, `6`, `8`.

More in [Strideable Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Strideable_Protocol/index.html) or [SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.1/protocol/Strideable/).

Comment: You are correct and I also looked into this but in my case I don't know the sequence in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to just write a global function that I used specifically for "planets":

```
func planetIncrement(planet: String) -> Int {
    return planet == "Venus" || planet == "Saturn" ? 2 : 1
}
```

Then just use the function in the `while` loop:

```
var i = 0
while i < planets.count {
    i += planetIncrement(planets[i])
}
```

The benefit is that both the function and the `while` loop are simple and easy to read. Tortured and complicated loop-logic is a recipe for bugs, so I would keep it simple.

The `loopIncrement` and `loopDecrement` functions you wrote are pretty cool, but they are possibly overkill and require you to basically write an entire function for every different use case anyway.

Another way you can rewrite a `while` loop is with a recursive function:

```
func iteratePlanets(planets: [String], index i: Int) {
    switch i {
    case let i where i >= planets.count:
        return
    case let i where planets[i] == "Venus" || planets[i] == "Saturn"
        iteratePlanets(planets, index: i + 2)
    case let i:
        iteratePlanets(planets, index: i + 1)
    }
}
```

That'll do the exact same thing as the `while` loop.

EDIT:

Maybe something like this would work:

```
extension Array {

    func loop(start: Int = 0, condition: (Int -> Bool)? = nil, increment: Element -> Int = { _ in 1 }, action: (Element -> ())? = nil) {
        var index = start
        while condition?(index) ?? (index < self.count) {
            action?(self[index])
            index += increment(self[index])
        }
    }
}
```

It loops, and allows you to provide custom conditions for terminating the loop, changing the increment amount, and even performing an action inside the loop, like this:

```
planets.loop(increment: { planet in
    return planet == "Venus" || planet == "Saturn" ? 2 : 1
})
```

My own feeling, though, is that this obscures the code. Since every use case is going to have its own internal loop-logic, you end up having to re-write the logic every time. Which means you essentially write a new function every time. And so you might as well just write the logic inside the loop, or write a simple, easy-to-understand external function so that everything is clear.

It's also possible to generalize this to all `CollectionType`s:

```
extension CollectionType {

    func loop(start start: Index.Distance = 0, condition: (Index -> Bool)? = nil, increment: Generator.Element -> Index.Distance = { _ in 1 }, action: (Generator.Element -> ())? = nil) {
        var index = self.startIndex.advancedBy(start)
        while condition?(index) ?? (index.distanceTo(self.endIndex) > 0) {
            let item = self[index]
            action?(item)
            index = index.advancedBy(increment(item))
        }
    }
}
```

This, for example, iterates over all the elements of a `Set`, printing each item...

```
Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).loop(action: { print($0) })
```

...and this iterates over an array in reverse order, printing each item:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].loop(start: 4, condition: { $0 >= 0 }, increment: { _ in -1}, action: { print($0) })
```

It actually mirrors the C-style for loop pretty well. With all of the parameters filled in, a function call looks like this:

```
planets.loop(
    start: 0,
    condition: { $0 < planets.count },
    increment: { $0 == "Venus" || $0 == "Saturn" ? 2 : 1 },
    action: { print($0) })
```

And using your `printObjects` example, you could use it like this:

```
printObjects.loop(
    increment: { $0.printCount >= 0 ? 0 : 1 },
    action: { 
        $0.printText = "This is line \($0.printCount)"
        print($0.printText)
        $0.printCount -= 1 })
```

EDIT:

I changed the function parameter name from `terminator` to `condition`, to make it more clear that the loop is supposed to continue as long as `condition` returns `true`, which is more consistent with how C-style for loops are written.

Comment: The problem here is that your function ist not global because it ist restricted to the planets array. What if it were an array of Integers? And what if the planets I want to skip are not know until the loop function is running? In you code you again have to know all this in advance like the other examples in this discussion. I want a replacement for the oly C-Style loops where the index was a variable. If I had all the information before running the loop then I could simply exchange your code with the arrays filter funtion.

Comment: I added sample code in my initial post. Maybe it will be clearer now the task at hand is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a little unclear on the problem, but here goes...

I presume that the actual problem looks something like this:

```
let planets = ["Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter"]
for (var i = 0; i < planets.count; i += 1) {
    let string = planets[i]
    if (string == "Venus" || string == "Saturn") {
        i += 2
    }
    print(string)
}
```

This yields:

```
Mercury
Venus
Jupiter
```

If that is right, then problem boils down to: as we cycle through the planets, how recently did we see Venus (or Saturn)? If we saw it recently enough, skip this iteration. The Swift for "skip this iteration" is `continue`. So all we have to do is keep track of how recently we saw Venus:

```
var marker = -100
for (ix,planet) in planets.enumerate() {
    if ix - marker < 3 {
        continue
    }
    if (planet == "Venus" || planet == "Saturn") {
        marker = ix
    }
    print(planet)
}
```

Having said that, I don't think it's how I would actually write this. What I would do is shorten the list of planets itself. Now you can do whatever you want to do with the list of remaining planets. So now our goal is to remove from the list of planets the planet that follows Venus (or Saturn) and the planet that follows that:

```
let fewerPlanets = planets.enumerate().filter {
    ix, planet in
    for ix in [ix-1, ix-2] {
        if ix >= 0 && (planets[ix] == "Venus" || planets[ix] == "Saturn") {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}.map {$1}
```

Now `fewerPlanets` is `["Mercury", "Venus", "Jupiter"]` and we can cycle through *that* and do whatever it is we want to do.